# external HDD with SATA & USB interface?

Tags: external-hard-drive, ssd, sata, esata

Anyone know of an external HDD that would have (in addition to USB) a SATA (eSATA) port/cable? i.e. Brand/Model.  Preferably one of the name brands so I have a better change of finding it here or locally if possible.

Background - In one location I want to use it is I would like to increase the performance by cabling it directly to the PC SATA port, HOWEVER I don't want to have to open up the PC to do this each time. I was thinking of running a SATA cable out through the PC case so I just plug it directly into the external HDD in question. Perhaps it should be also externally powered too so I don't need to run a power cable out from the PC power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Akasa Integral P2 E-SATA AK-ENP2SATA-BK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000TV070S/ref=pd_lpo_k2_dp_sr_1?pf_rd_p=103612307&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B0012V4VNI&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=1SAMMYHJ0SZD7F9N93F0) - it connects SATA or PATA to USB or eSATA.

Comment: thank looks good - so it seems to have it's own power?  i.e. so the only cable you need to feed into the PC itself is the eSATA cable correct? (i.e. no need to connect to the internal PC power connector)

Comment: That's correct - it has an external power adaptor.